# How can i achieve local persistence in my electron app?

Tags: angular, database, electron, persistence

I am building an electron app with an angular frontend which monitors the active window on the computer to track the user's activities. However I am having difficulties figuring out how to properly persist this data.

I have been doing a lot of research and seen people suggest IndexedDB/dexie.js, localForage, couchDB, SQLite etc. But I am struggling to actually make a decision on which technology to use because I cannot comprehend how to actually implement them in my electron application - and the documentation of actual electron implementation is very sparse.

I think the reason that I am struggling so much, is that there might some key concepts to creating an electron app that I am not understanding properly.

I think i might be wrong in making the distinction that the main.ts (electron) is backend and my angular application is front end, where I instead should consider it as a whole. Maybe someone could elaborate on this?

This thought has kept me away from using something like couchDB where the boilerplate would look like this (placed in index.html -> frontend):

```html
    <html>
      <head>
          <!-- Include Dexie -->
          <script src="https://unpkg.com/dexie@latest/dist/dexie.js"></script>

          <script>
              //
              // Define your database
              //
              var db = new Dexie("friend_database");
              db.version(1).stores({
                  friends: 'name,shoeSize'
              });

              //
              // Put some data into it
              //
              db.friends.put({name: "Nicolas", shoeSize: 8}).then (function(){
                  //
                  // Then when data is stored, read from it
                  //
                  return db.friends.get('Nicolas');
              }).then(function (friend) {
                  //
                  // Display the result
                  //
                  alert ("Nicolas has shoe size " + friend.shoeSize);
              }).catch(function(error) {
                 //
                 // Finally don't forget to catch any error
                 // that could have happened anywhere in the
                 // code blocks above.
                 //
                 alert ("Ooops: " + error);
              });
          </script>
      </head>
    </html>
```

This seems like an issue to me, since I am actually getting the data for the active window from what i consider the backend.

To understand my problem a little better, here are some snippets of some code I consider important to answer this question.

First and foremost i have created a Poller.ts which as the name suggests polls. I use it to continuously get the active window running on the PC.

**Poller.ts**

```js
    import * as EventEmitter from 'events';


    export default class Poller extends EventEmitter {
      private timeout: number;

      constructor(timeout = 5000) {
        super();
        this.timeout = timeout;
      }

      public poll(): void {
        setTimeout(() => this.emit('poll'), this.timeout);
      }

      public onPoll(cb): void {
        this.on('poll', cb);
      }
    }
```

In my Main.ts I then use this poller in conjunction with the [active-win](https://github.com/sindresorhus/active-win) library to get the active window.

**Main.ts**

```js
    ipcMain.on('tracking:start', (e) => {
      poller.poll();
      (async () => {
        console.log('Starting tracking');
      })();
    });

    ipcMain.on('tracking:stop', () => {
      (async () => {
        console.log('Stopping tracking');
      })();
    });

    poller.onPoll(() => {
      (async () => {
        let activeWindow = await activeWin();
        console.log(activeWindow);
      })();
      poller.poll();
    });
```

And the polling process is started/stopped from the frontend by an event sent by the ipcRenderer.

**Angular component**

```js
    public startTracking() {
        console.log('starting tracking');
        if (this.electronService.isElectronApp) {
          this.electronService.ipcRenderer.send('tracking:start');
        }
      }

      public stopTracking() {
        console.log('stopping tracking');
        if (this.electronService.isElectronApp) {
          this.electronService.ipcRenderer.send('tracking:stop');
        }
      }
```

Hence from my understanding I should be persisting the data from the polling function which is located in what i consider the backend, which does not align with my understanding of the persistence libraries listed above.

I expect to be able to store each window log as a separate entry and do some querying and categorization of the data.

So i hope any of you can shed some light on what I am misunderstanding, or suggest a library which would fit my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that part of Electron documentation is sparse is because those mechanisms aren't from Electron, they are regular browser technologies (i.e. Chrome, Firefox, etc). You should look up what you need on MDN (the Mozilla Developer Network): https://developer.mozilla.org. For example, try searching on Google for "mdn localstorage", "mdn indexeddb", "mdn cachestorage", or "mdn cookies", and you'll start to find documentation on topics about storing content locally offline.

EDIT: Note, you can't use things like CouchDB or SQLite in a web browser, and those things also are not Electron-specific. You can search for "Node.js CouchDB" or "Node.js SQLite" to find resources on those, because Electron is written on top of Node.js.

Anything that you can use in a Node.js project, you can use in Electron. Similarly, in browser technology that you can use in Chrome, you can use in Electron, because Electron combines the Chrome browser engine with Node.js.

Comment: Yea, I am aware that none of those libs are actually Electron specific. But my problem still is that it seems like the frontend should be responsibile for a lot of the database logic when using many of the suggested libs for Electron, and this is what puts me off. Since the main process is the only thing with access to system processes, it seems weird that the frontend should be responsible for persisting this data.

This would mean that I would have to emit an event from the ipcrenderer to the main process, to then return the actual data back to the front end everytime i poll the active app

Comment: @JonasMohrPedersen But why would you do that? You can write "backend" code right in the renderer, but that doesn't mean you will have to mix it with UI code. You can still cleanly separate the two things (f.e. use Redux or something). If you have those tools in the environment, why not use them? It's not like there's a server, and you don't have to (de)serialize data; I would consider having the code in the renderer perfectly fine. Plus! You can also send references to/from main to renderer, and vice versa. You don't have to specifically use IPC.